# Настройка django-ckeditor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, pycharm

Здравствуйте.

Установил и настроил этот визуальный редактор - все вроде работает. Но тут нужно было сделать загрузку видео с ютуба и настроить стили отображения кода. Скачал для этого два модуля youtube и codesnippet вроде работают, но только по отдельности.

Проблема в том, что на панель выводится только один элемент это либо codesnippet либо youtube а как их вместе отобразить на toolbare я не пойму?
Если ставлю ютуб, то исчезает codesnippet, если ставлю codesnippet, то пропадает ютуб.

Все регулировал в файле конфигурации скедитора а также в settings.py тоже менял настройки скедитора - но ничего не получилось такое впечатление, что в тулбар можно всего добавить один элемент!

Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: добавляли через config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet' ? Без того что сделали с настройками только готовым решением можно ответить.